# Export data from excel to a database table using ClosedXML example

Tags: database, excel, closedxml

i have to read rows of data from an excel file which has only a column and then i have to save the rows in a table in database .
In my project i have to use ClosedXML .dll .
I have search but i couldn't find an example .
Can you please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the `ClosedXML` part, you can refer to the documentation at https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Finding-and-extracting-the-data

```
private static void Main()
{
  List<String> categories;
  List<String> companies;
  ExtractCategoriesCompanies("NorthwindData.xlsx", out categories, out companies);

  // Do something with the categories and companies
}

private static void ExtractCategoriesCompanies(string northwinddataXlsx, out List<string> categories, out List<string> companies)
{
  categories = new List<string>();
  const int coCategoryId = 1;
  const int coCategoryName = 2;

  var wb = new XLWorkbook(northwinddataXlsx);
  var ws = wb.Worksheet("Data");

  // Look for the first row used
  var firstRowUsed = ws.FirstRowUsed();

  // Narrow down the row so that it only includes the used part
  var categoryRow = firstRowUsed.RowUsed();

  // Move to the next row (it now has the titles)
  categoryRow = categoryRow.RowBelow();

  // Get all categories
  while (!categoryRow.Cell(coCategoryId).IsEmpty())
  {
    String categoryName = categoryRow.Cell(coCategoryName).GetString();
    categories.Add(categoryName);

    categoryRow = categoryRow.RowBelow();
  }

  // There are many ways to get the company table.
  // Here we're using a straightforward method.
  // Another way would be to find the first row in the company table
  // by looping while row.IsEmpty()

  // First possible address of the company table:
  var firstPossibleAddress = ws.Row(categoryRow.RowNumber()).FirstCell().Address;
  // Last possible address of the company table:
  var lastPossibleAddress = ws.LastCellUsed().Address;

  // Get a range with the remainder of the worksheet data (the range used)
  var companyRange = ws.Range(firstPossibleAddress, lastPossibleAddress).RangeUsed();

  // Treat the range as a table (to be able to use the column names)
  var companyTable = companyRange.AsTable();

  // Get the list of company names
  companies = companyTable.DataRange.Rows()
    .Select(companyRow => companyRow.Field("Company Name").GetString())
    .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** The below only gets you a populated datatable. You'll then need to load that datatable into your database. You don't say which database this is, but for SQL Server you would use the `SqlBulkCopy` class (see [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=sqlclient-dotnet-core-2.0), which also has an example).

Late to the party, but try this:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel(string path, string sheetname = "", bool hasHeader = true)
{
  using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(path))
  {
    IXLWorksheet worksheet;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetname))
      worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();
    else
      worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == sheetname);

    var rangeRowFirst = worksheet.FirstRowUsed().RowNumber();
    var rangeRowLast = worksheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
    var rangeColFirst = worksheet.FirstColumnUsed().ColumnNumber();
    var rangeColLast = worksheet.LastColumnUsed().ColumnNumber();

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

    for (int col = rangeColFirst; col <= rangeColLast; col++)
      tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? worksheet.FirstRowUsed().Cell(col).Value.ToString() : $"Column {col}");

    Logger("started creating datatable");

    rangeRowFirst = rangeRowFirst + (hasHeader ? 1 : 0);
    var colCount = rangeColLast - rangeColFirst;
    for (int rowNum = rangeRowFirst; rowNum <= rangeRowLast; rowNum++)
    {
      List<string> colValues = new List<string>();
      for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
      {
        colValues.Add(worksheet.Row(rowNum).Cell(col).Value.ToString());
      }
      tbl.Rows.Add(colValues.ToArray());
    }

    Logger("finished creating datatable");
    return tbl;
  }
}
```

and call like this:

```
var datatable = GetDataTableFromExcel(fileName, sheetName);
```

If you're using (the excellent and free in its basic form) [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), you can inspect the `datatable` using `datatable.Dump();`